# Jquery UI Autocomplete Not Working on IE10

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

I am making a website but I cannot get to work this Jquery plugin on IE 10. This is my code for the HEAD:

```
  <head>

      <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/style/Style.css'>
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css' />
       <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
       <script src='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js'></script>
       <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
              var availableTags = [";

              while($row5 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "'" . $row5['solicitante'] . "',";
               }
                mysqli_close($con);

            echo "];
                  $( '#tags' ).autocomplete({
                    source: availableTags
                  });
                });
                </script>

</head>
```

And this is the object TAGS code:

```
 <form action="../procesar/procesar_nombre.php" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td> <b>Nombre</b> <td>
                <td> <input id="tags" type="text" name="nombre" size=30 maxlength=20/> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>  </td>
                <td> <input type="submit" value="Revisar"> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

This works just fine on Google Chrome, but not in IE10, I tried researching something about the situation but with no answers.

The source of the page looks like this on the web browser, for those who do not get what I am trying to do. HEAD:

```
   <head>

            <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/style/Style.css'>
            <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css' />
            <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
            <script src='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js'></script>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                  var availableTags = ['Maria F Romero','Carla Custodio','Julio Cesar Pacheco','Dorimar Balza','Miguel Morales','Johana Rodriguez','Oswaldo Zarate','sinnombre','Ronald Grimaldo','Gerardo Leon','Gelenny Lara',];
                  $( '#tags' ).autocomplete({
                    source: availableTags
                  });
                });
                </script>

</head>
```

This is the object:

```
  <form action="../procesar/procesar_nombre.php" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td> <b>Nombre</b> <td>
                <td> <input id="tags" type="text" name="nombre" size=30 maxlength=20/> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>  </td>
                <td> <input type="submit" value="Revisar"> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: did you got any console error while running your site on IE10?

Comment: Are you trying to run PHP code in javascript?

Comment: That REALLY looks like PHP to me.

Comment: I did not get any error @Arun_C_C.

Comment: Yes, it is PHP. I am using the while loop to make the javascript code, so that has the values of my DB.

Comment: Looks like you're mixing JS, HTML and PHP, but it's hard to tell what's going on from the top code fragment.

Comment: I just updated the question so you guys can see what I did

Comment: Open your browser's console and check for any error output. F12

Comment: James Gandolfini is not in the available tags

Comment: do that  last comma neeeded after 'Gelenny Lara',

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the question was to add the following line of code in the head of the document:

```
 <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=Edge'>
```

Now it works good on IE10

Answer (score 0):

Javascript = client side.

Php = server side.

You can't combine them the way you use