# Text input element no longer offering autocomplete suggestions in IE10 (Worked in IE9)

Tags: html, autocomplete, internet-explorer-10

Users of my web application are complaining that the browser's auto-complete functionality is no longer offering suggestions as they type in a form on my web site since upgrading to Internet Explorer 10. The exact same page, for the same user shows auto-complete suggestions just fine in IE9.

Here is an example of a text input from the page that has the problem, although all of my text inputs seem to have the same problem.

```
<input name="Organization" tabIndex="4" 
       id="Organization" style="width: 120px;"  
       type="text" size="30" maxLength="255" 
       autocomplete="on" value=""/>
```

Things I've tried:

- Retest with same user/site/conditions on IE9 (Autocomplete still works)
- Confirm Browser setting for Autocompleting forms is enabled
- View source on the page to make SURE the autocomplete="on" value is set.

Anyone have any ideas?

**Update:**
I set up this very basic example of a form ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FZFug/2/)) and it still isn't doing autocomplete. Is this feature simply broken in IE10?

Comment: Hmm, after looking around the internet it seems that this is a known bug with IE10. There's a funny bug report on Microsoft that guy from Microsoft asks the user to do a virus scan to fix it :D see here http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie10-windows_7/internet-explorer-10-autocomplete-not-working/2aefd8dd-8372-415e-bd2f-6ddc4c4ba80e  Can you try adding the following `<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=Edge'>`

Comment: I saw that one too (did a lot of Googling before posting the Q). Ugh! Wanted to slap the Tech who responded with that.  I'll give that  meta tag a try, though I don't get why it would help.

Comment: Haha! I can't see why it would work either to be honest, but it seemed to work for the OP in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17454620/jquery-ui-autocomplete-not-working-on-ie10

Comment: That question is about the jQuery Autocomplete plugin, not the built in browser autocomplete field.

Comment: Ah yeah good point, I seen another solution, but it involved altering something in the registry, not exactly a solution that can be passed on to end users!

Comment: Found that too. Doesn't apply anyway. That only works if a specific registry key is missing, which it wasn't in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the example you have given on fiddle, and its working for me. 
Following are the changes i have done in browser's Auto complete settings to make it work.

[image: Auto Complete Configuration]

You can see the text in text box as a result of autocomplete feature of browser

[image: Auto complete Example]

Comment: Confirmed those are checked, but still no dice. What exact version of IE are you using? I'm on 10.0.9200.16844