# JQuery UI autocomplete not working in IE 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, internet-explorer

Wanted to get a solution for this problem, when I use jquery 2.x with jquery UI, everything seems to work fine, but when I use jquery 1.x with jquery UI no action is triggering for autocomplete. When I tried to debug it in IE, there was no error found.

Sample import that works:

```
<script src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Sample import that never works:

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Autocomplete sample code:

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#automplete-1" ).autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        source: function( request, response ) {
                processRequest(request, response);
        },
        select:function(event, ui){
            populateAddress(ui.item.idx);
        }
    });
 });
```

This is how the code looks like within processRequest

```
function processRequest(request, response, country){

    $.getJSON('MyRestService', function(jsonResponse) {
                //some code
        });     

        response($.map(javaScriptArray, function(item, index) {
            return {
                value: item,
                idx: index,
                label: item
            };
        }));
    });
}
```

Comment: which IE are you talking about? jq 2.x are not suppose to work with old stuff

Comment: I am using IE10 but I want the implementation to be compatible with older IEs as well, that's when I thought of trying jquery 1.x but JQuery UI doesn't seem to be compatible here.

Comment: the reply bellow give it away .. :)

Comment: Similiar post http://stackoverflow.com/a/17455734/4487940

Comment: I tried that, but still its not working :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved, it was not an autocomplete problem, its more of a CORS problem in IE.

I added this line to solve the problem

```
$.support.cors = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

With jquery 1.7.1 you have to use older version of jquery UI(1.10.4)

Comment: I tried using 1.8 but it was not working. Is 1.8 compatible with JQuery 1.7?

Comment: I thinks 1.10.4 has legacy support for older jquery 1.6+.
If you are trying to run this on older IE 8+, then double check your JSON objects or arrays for  trailing comma  IE version less then 10 are very strict on this leftover trailing commas

Comment: Please also add fiddle of your code, so we can debug more.

Comment: This is my source actually. It works fine on Firefox and Chrome

         $(function() {
            $( "#automplete-1" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 3,
    source: function( request, response ) {
                                       //perform AJAX call
    },
    select:function(event, ui){
     alert(ui.item.value);
    }
            });
         });

Comment: Which IE it is exactly not working, I tested jquery UI example on IE8
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote
and it is working fine.

Comment: I was trying in IE10. I'm using older version of jquery because I need to ensure that the implementation works for older IE browsers as well